# Block ubuntu running device from accesing a specific local ip

Tags: firewall

I have a tiny server running 24/7 and I would like to make it unable from accesing my router which is on the 192.168.1.1 IP.

Comment: Router IP is not any LAN IP, probably is also the gateway (to access internet). But you could block all ports (transport level). Seems an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), add more details to your question about the setup and the reasons behind

Comment: Agree, we need more context. However, and based on my current understanding this iptables rule: `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o enp3s0 -d 192.168.1.1 -j DROP` might do what you want. Change `enp3s0` to your interface name. The rule might need to placed within the bigger context of your overall iptables rule set, if you have any. Check via `sudo iptables -xvnL`.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I want to expose that device to the internet (Its an radxa E23 board, noting fancy) and this board is allready is isolated to my other devices in the network, but i want to be sure that in case of something bad , the attacker cannot acces the ISP's ont , which is on the 192.168.1.1 IP,

Comment: If your router also provides DNS and/or DHCP services, you might need to allow those ports before dropping other packets to that IP.

Comment: I drawed a simple "schematic" of my home network. [link](https://imgur.com/a/4f9WRnu)https://imgur.com/a/4f9WRnu
My goal is to block the Server From accesing the ont, but i want it to still be able to talk to the internet

Comment: Seems you just want to put your host/server on a [DMZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29#DMZ_host). The ONT usually also have a router and switch, so you are overcomplicating things if you added the other switch+router just for this issue. If you can't enter the ONT setup or doesn't have any feature similar to DMZ you could Internet→ONT→router with more capabilities or OpenWRT→LAN and isolated server. Please add the photo and any more details to the post, not here.

Comment: @PabloBianchi It seems that i forgot DMZ on since the last time i tryed to thinker , oups. And it doesnt work, if i do a curl 192.168.1.1 , i still can get the ont's config page